# Clear DocumentDB Collection before inserting documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to know how to clear documentdb collection before inserting new documents. I am using datafactory pipeline activity to fecth data from on-prem sql server and insert into documentdb collection. The frequency is set to every 2 hrs. So when the next cycle runs, I want to first clear the exisitng data in documentdb collection. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to programmatically delete the collection and recreate it with the same name. Our test scripts do this automatically. There is the potential for this to fail due to a subtle race condition, but we've found that adding a half second delay between the delete and recreate avoids this.

Alternatively, it would be possible to fetch every document id and then delete them one at a time. This would be most efficiently done from a stored procedure (sproc) so you didn't have to send it all over the wire, but it would still be consuming RUs and take time.

Comment: How would one go about doing it the Stored Procedure way?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/sprocs/deleteSomeDocuments.coffee) is a sproc I have written that allows you to pass in a filter expression and it will delete all of those documents. Note, if you are using documentdb-utils, it will automatically keep calling the sproc until finished. If you just use the sproc, you'll have to keep calling it yourself until no continuation token comes back.

If you don't know CoffeeScript, just cut and paste it in [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try) and it'll compile it to JavaScript for you.

Comment: Correction, that particular sproc does not handle the continuation token, but you could easily add it using as an example one of the other sprocs in that folder that does.